# How to optimize a query having multiple like conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I've following query into which I'm filling temporary table from multiple select statements which are using multiple like conditions but I'm unable to optimize the query.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tempTable') is not null

    drop table #tempTable

select totalProcessed=(select  COUNT(*) as totalProcessed 
from DetailItem di
inner join DownloadFile df 
on di.DownloadFileID = df.DownLoadID
where 
(CONVERT(date, di.CompletionTime)) = '2018-01-31' and
di.DetailItemName<>'99999999' 
and df.CompanyID = 164 
and (df.filename like '%OA73030%'  or df.filename like '%OA73035%'
or df.FileName like '%OA77030%' or df.filename like '%OA77035%')),

totalErrored=(select  COUNT(*) as totalErrored 
from DetailItem di
inner join DownloadFile df 
on di.DownloadFileID = df.DownLoadID
where 
(di.CompletionDetail  like '%Not found%'or di.CompletionDetail  like '%error%')  and 
CONVERT(date, di.CompletionTime) ='2018-01-31' 
and di.DetailItemName<>'99999999' 
and df.CompanyID = 164 
and (df.FileName like '%OA73030%' or df.filename like '%OA73035%'
or df.FileName like '%OA77030%' or df.filename like '%OA77035%')),

totalSuccess=(select  COUNT(*) as totalSuccess 
from DetailItem di
inner join DownloadFile df 
on di.DownloadFileID = df.DownLoadID
where 
(di.CompletionDetail not like '%error%' and di.CompletionDetail not like '%Not Found%') and 
CONVERT(date, di.CompletionTime) ='2018-01-31' 
and di.DetailItemName<>'99999999' 
and df.CompanyID = 164
and (df.FileName like '%OA73030%' or df.filename like '%OA73035%'
or df.FileName like '%OA77030%' or df.filename like '%OA77035%')) into #tempTable
select totalProcessed, totalErrored, totalSuccess,cast(round(((totalSuccess*100.0)/totalProcessed),2) as decimal(5,2)) as '%ProcessedSuccessfully',
(totalProcessed-totalSuccess)as 'TotalRe-Processed(2ndBD)',0 as 'TotalSuccessfullyProcessedOutOfRe-order(3rdBD)',0 as 'TotalSLAMissed' 
from #tempTable
```

Comment: Simplify your question, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: It has various like conditions which are similar I want to put that at single place if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that search values comes dynamically and no way to predict of what going to be selected. Then, you cannot do a lot with constructions like:

```
WHERE df.filename like '%OA73030%'  or df.filename like '%OA73035%'
or df.FileName like '%OA77030%' or df.filename like '%OA77035%'
```

Since there is no way to rewrite it to:

```
WHERE df.filename like IN ('%OA73030%','%OA73035%','%OA77030%','%OA77035%')
```

However, you entire logic of your query can be very much optimized this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalProcessed
,       COUNT(CASE WHEN    di.CompletionDetail LIKE '%Not found%' OR di.CompletionDetail LIKE '%error%'  THEN 1 END) AS totalErrored
,       COUNT(CASE WHEN    di.CompletionDetail NOT LIKE '%error%' AND di.CompletionDetail NOT LIKE '%Not Found%'  THEN 1 END) AS totalErrored
,       COUNT(CASE WHEN    di.CompletionDetail NOT LIKE '%error%' AND di.CompletionDetail NOT LIKE '%Not Found%'  THEN 1 END) AS totalSuccess
FROM   DetailItem di
       INNER JOIN DownloadFile df ON di.DownloadFileID = df.DownLoadID
WHERE  di.CompletionTime between '2018-01-31' AND '2018-01-31 23:59:59'
       AND di.DetailItemName <> '99999999'
       AND df.CompanyID = 164
       AND (   df.filename LIKE '%OA73030%'
               OR df.filename LIKE '%OA73035%'
               OR df.FileName LIKE '%OA77030%'
               OR df.filename LIKE '%OA77035%' );
```

In this case the data engine have to search data only once for all aggregates instead of four times.

Next to that, your approach of trimming time is not SARGable:

```
( CONVERT(DATE, di.CompletionTime)) = '2018-01-31'
```

and it has to be rewritten to:

```
di.CompletionTime between '2018-01-31' AND '2018-01-31 23:59:59'
```

Otherwise possible index on CompletionTime will not be used

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure there is an index on `DownloadFile.CompanyID` and make sure that your query uses it by checking the execution plan (if it does not use the index then use a hint), other than that there is not much you can do with a query like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex inside like condition like below

```
df.filename like '%OA7[37]03[05]%'
```

<kbd>**[see live demo](http://rextester.com/XRWJSJ72780)**</kbd>